# How can I avoid unnecessary blocking in a multithreaded program?

Tags: java, synchronization

Given 2 methods, `methodA()` and `methodB()`, is there a way to synchronize these such that `methodA()` isn't synchronized with itself? i.e. many threads may execute `methodA()` simultanously.

- Calls to `methodA()` should block until `methodB()` is not running.
- Calls to `methodB()` should block until neither `methodB()` or `methodA()` is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ReentrantReadWriteLock.

In methodA lock on readLock and in methodB lock on writeLock. This will allow to call methodA by several threads, but not methodA and methodB (or methodB and methodB) simultaneously.

More background:
ReadLock allows parallel read. WriteLock is exclusive, no more reads or writes are allowed. Usually if there are some threads reading and some thread wants to write, further read requests are queued until write thread does the job. It's called fair/unfair algorithm and can be configured in constructor if necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't all calls to methodA wait for the previous call to release the lock on readLock?